# Is it possible to extract x,y coordinate of an element in LaTeX?

Tags: rendering

I'm looking to programmatically generate PDF documents using LaTeX, but at the same time, keep track of where the elements are getting rendered (i.e. the x,y coordinates of `\image` elements or the `\section` element etc. ) in each page of each document.

Is there any way that I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Package `zref` and its `savepos` feature, e.g. `\zsavepos{myimage}` and `\zposx{myimage}` and `\zposy{myimage}`, where `myimage` is a label name you can design yourself. (of course, only once).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Hi, Christopher, can you please elaborate? Perhaps, by posting as an asnwer? Thanks!

Comment: I wonder a little bit about your statement of `in each page of each document`. This is too broad.

Comment: I think this is essentially what SyncTeX is for, so it would make sense to use it somehow (if possible), rather than re-implement everything from scratch with `savepos` or whatever.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer By `in each page of each document`, I mean that I want the x,y cooridnates w.r.t to the page rather than w.r.t the entire document, if that makes any sense.